# PHP while numbers in each row

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
$result10=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blog_articles WHERE fk_semikatagori_id = 9") or die(mysql_error());
?>

<?php
    $index = 1;
    while($row10 = mysql_fetch_array($result10)) {
        if($index%2==0) {
            echo "<span class=\"f\">";
            echo $row10['english_navn'];
            echo "</span><br />";
        }
        else {
            echo "<p><span class=\"f\">";
            echo $row10['english_navn'];
            echo "</span></p><br />";
            echo "<p>";
            echo $row10['english_tekst'];
            echo "</p><br />";
        }
        $index++;
    }

?>
```

Any ideas how I can display the number for each row?
I want it to start from 1.
I cant display the id from Mysql because it doesnt start from 1.

Comment: You already have a counter setup. Just output it. `echo($index);`

Comment: Recommendation: use single quotes for echo, like `echo <'span class="f"'>;` that way you won't have to use escape characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could for example use a [for() loop](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) instead of a `while()` loop,

```
for ($index = 0; $row10 = mysql_fetch_array($result10); $index++)
{ 
    ...
    echo $index; 
}
```

Then the counter would be echoed.

Comment: You should count before, instead of counting inside the loop. You only have to do one query instead of querying the database everytime

Comment: @DasSaffe, not sure what you are talking about? The query is outside the loop? $result10 is a resource? You need a counter inside the loop?

Comment: you are right, my bad. Havn't paid attention, mate.

Comment: Hehe, no probs, thought I missed something :P

Answer (score 0):

```
$index = 1;

while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) 
{
    // display the number for each row
    echo $index;

    // other code...

    // increment number
    $index++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution that you can get are the follow:

Make a for statement:

```
<?php 
for($idx=1; $row = mysql_fetch_array($result10); $idx++) {
    ...
}
?>
```

as said before or use the follow:

```
<?php
$idx = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result10)) {
    ...
    $idx++;
}
?>
```

I would recommend you to make a like upgrade in your select statement to get a faster result (if you start get many rows as result):

```
from: SELECT * FROM blog_articles WHERE fk_semikatagori_id = 9
to: 
    SELECT 
        english_navn
        , english_tekst 
    FROM blog_articles 
    WHERE 
        fk_semikatagori_id = 9
```

Because you are using just these 2 columns into your loop but you are making MySQL engine get all columns from this table.

I hope it help you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the help, it worked.

Here is the code if anyone else can use it.

```
                <?php
            $index = 1;
            for ($index2 = 1; $row10 = mysql_fetch_array($result10); $index2++)
            {
                if($index%2==0)
                {
                    echo "<span class=\"f\">";
                    echo $row10['english_navn'];
                    echo $index2;
                    echo "</span><br />";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "<p><span class=\"f\">";
                    echo $row10['english_navn'];
                    echo "</span></p><br />";
                    echo "<p>";
                    echo $index2;
                    echo $row10['english_tekst'];
                    echo "</p><br />";
                }
                $index++;
                }
                ?>
```